# Client WebSocket not connecting to server in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I've followed every tutorial known to StackOverflow and it seems like none of them have done the trick. I'm trying to connect a client to a server with WebSockets and it keeps giving me the `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:6000/' failed`. It has to be something on my client side because I get no errors on my server

Server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const WebSocket = require('ws')

var wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 6000 })
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('Connected WebSocket')
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log(message)
    })
})
```

Client:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:6000");

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(event.data)
}
```

I am using Glitch to host my website if that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found an API called 'Socket.io' that fixed the problem. You can find the documentation here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/

It makes data much easier to send and receive since you don't need to worry about changing json into a blob and back again.

Comment: not really an API. a library with fallbacks to other forms of transport.